# How to fix error: "Call to a member function listSpatialIndexes() on null" and why is it happening?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate -e prod
```

When I run it, I'm getting error

> "Call to a member function listSpatialIndexes() on null".

Please, help me by explain why it happens and how to fix it.

Additionally, the command `"php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate -e dev"`, ends with the error

> "[ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping
>   file."

Comment: Check on the similar (same) issue reported on github. Issue was registering event subscriber too late. Maybe that can be helpful for you also: https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis/issues/9

Comment: Sorry, but where should I register it? Is the registration somewhere in config files? The configuration was given for ZF2, but I'm using Symfony4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that variable server_version in pgsql in doctrine.yaml didn't exist. To resolve the problem, add

```
 pgsql:
    ...
    server_version: <insert your server version here, in my case 11.3>
```

You can see server's version by adding echo($this->getServerVersion()) and then exit(1) in the line 452 in vendor's file vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php.